# Finding the lowest number in an array using split('') and reverse();

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find the min value of an array, and am trying to do it by sorting the array, and then reversing the array, and then calling the very first index of the array.

Unfortunately with what I have been trying, I keep getting 9. (don't know why) Can anybody take a quick look at what I have been doing and bail me out here? (i'm using js)

```
var minny = [4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 1, 11, 25];


var smallest = function (minny){
    minny =  minny.sort('');

    var sorted = minny + " ";

    sorted =  minny.reverse('').join('');
    return sorted[0];
}

console.log(smallest(minny))
```

Comment: Two things - `sort()` is in ascending order already, no need to reverse. Also, JS doesn't sort how you might expect - 11 comes before 9 (it does the check char by char, so sees the 1 and puts it before 9, and then it sees the second 1, but doesn't understand the notion of it being 11 and being > 9 - it sorts like strings)

Comment: Do you just want the min value? You can also try `Math.min.apply(null, [your array])`

Comment: Why are you passing strings to `sort()` and `reverse()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling minny.sort('') which is using the default natural sort, so 11 and 25 end up near the beginning because of the 1 and 2.

What you have to do is call sort with a function that compares numbers, such as:

```
minny.sort(function(a,b) { return b-a; });
```

This will sort minny the way you want it.

There is no need to even call reverse and join afterwards, just return the first item. "return sorted[0]" is fine but will fail if there are no items, so you might just want to call "return sorted.shift()" instead. This will return the first item too, but won't fail if the array is empty.

PS. your call to minny.reverse also has an empty string as a parameter. That's not needed, reverse takes no parameters.

Answer (score 3):

By default the sort method sorts elements alphabetically(11 comes before 9) and therefore you need to add a compare function as a param.

```
var smallest = function (minny) {
    minny = minny.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
    return minny[0];
}

console.log(smallest(minny))
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ywc1uf17/).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, you could just do

```
return minny.sort()[0];
```

So, your full code example becomes

```
var minny = [4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 1, 11, 25];


var smallest = function (minny){
    return minny.sort()[0];
}

console.log(smallest(minny))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` sorts alphabetically by string representation, so in your case it would result in `1, 11, 2, 2, 25, ...`. You have to provide a comparison function for correct integer sorting, although in your specific case it doesn't really make a difference.

```
var smallest = function (minny){
    minny = minny.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    return minny[0];
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkndgjfh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Using sort is fairly short code to write, and it will return the correct number if you use `minny.sort(function(a,b){return a-b})[0]`.

If you have a large unordered array you are running the comparison many times **and** you are sorting the array, which is not usually what you want to do to an array.

It may be better to just iterate the members and compare each just once to the lowest fond so far.

```
var minny= [4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 1, 11, 25];

var smallest= function(minny){
    var min= Infinity;
    minny.forEach(function(next){
        if(next<min) min= next;
    });
    return min;
}
```

Or use Math.min, if this is code golf:

```
Math.min.apply(Array,minny);
```